# How to get sum in Table Rows (Total Price) using SPAN name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am building shopping cart using J2EE. I am showing values (Product Picture, Product Name, Product price, Quantity and Total price of quantities). What I want is there are multiple rows. So how can I calculate sum(Total Price) of all the products using JavaScript?

**Code**

```
var table = $("#cartTB");
$.each(data,function(i, value)
{
    table.append
    ('<tr class="cart_item"><td class="product-remove"><a title="Remove this item" class="remove" href="#">×</a> </td>
    <td class="product-thumbnail"><a href=""><img width="145" height="145" alt="poster_1_up" class="shop_thumbnail" src="'+ value.productPic +'"></a></td>
    <td class="product-name"><a href="">'+ value.productName +'</a></td>
    <td class="product-price"><span id="onePrice" class="amount">'+ value.productPrice +'</span> </td>
    <td class="product-quantity"><div class="quantity buttons_added"><input type="button" id="mButton" class="minus" onclick="priceCalc()" value="-"><input type="number" id="qty" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="'+ value.qty +'" min="0" step="1"><input type="button" id="pButton" class="plus" onclick="priceCalc()" value="+"></div></td>
    <td class="product-subtotal"><span id="totProPrice" name="totP" class="amount">'+ value.productPrice +'</span></td></tr>'
    );
```

**I tried this. But it gives me 0 always.**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            var totalValue = 0;
            $("#cartTB span").each(function() {
                totalValue += parseFloat($(this).find('.totP').text());
            });
            alert(totalValue);
        });
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide a functional example that people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can also click `<>` icon in the header in edit mode to add a demo. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see an element with class `totP` in your example, which might be part of the problem... `.totP` would search for all elements with _class_ `totP`.

Comment: @AlexanderNied **totP** is the name of the SPAN

Comment: Yes, but this line `.find('.totP')` will _not find that based on name.  You would need to change it to `.find('[name="totP"]')` if you wanted to select by `name` attribute.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Now I tried. But It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use es6 .map()

```
let total_price = 0;
 //this will loop through your array
data.map(val => {
    total_price += parseInt(val.productPrice);
});
```